# xcode-select -print-path is not display anything

Tags: xcode

I have install Command Line Tool for Xcode 5.1, but when is use command "xcode-select -print-path" on my terminal, my terminal doesn't show anything.

This is the example :

`Robbys-MacBook-Pro:~ robbywidyahartono$ xcode-select -print-path
 Robbys-MacBook-Pro:~ robbywidyahartono$`

Why "xcode-select -print-path" command doesn't show anything?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The path may not be set. Set it first

```
xcode-select --switch /path/to/xcode.app
```

Also as Yosemite is recent, there's a lot of patches coming out - so make sure you're up to date on Mac OS, Xcode, and the command line tools.

Comment: The results were similiar, "xcode-select --print-path" command still doesn't show anything. Is there a setting i need to use xcode-select?

Comment: Still the same, that command still doesn't show anything, no warning or error message

Comment: Also, as silly as it may sound - check the App Store for updates and make sure xcode and Xcode command line tools are up to date.

Comment: Okay, i think i need to check the App Store first.. Thank you

Comment: Case closed. I have 3 xcode installed on my mac, and i need setting in my bash_profile. Thank you